# retrieve boolean value of checkbox jquery/html

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, input

I have a webserver running, which has a page containing a table with description and checkbox. What I need is to modify the row, therefore modify the state of the checkbox.

But when I click on the row to open a window from which I can edit the values, the checkbox is always set to false, even if it was true.

Here is the piece of my code that doesn't work:

```
if (selected_obj){
                      var markup = [
                          '<div class="confirmOverlay" id="edit_row_overlay">',
                          '<div id="edit_row_box" class="confirmBox">',
                          '<h1>Edit Row</h1>',
                          '<fieldset class="field">',
                          ' <label for="id_name">name:</label>',
                          ' <input type="text" name="name" id="id_name" value='+selected_obj.name+'>',
                          '</fieldset>',
                          '<fieldset class="field">',
                          ' <label for="id_description">description:</label>',
                          ' <input type="text" name="description" id="id_description" value='+selected_obj.description+'>',
                          '</fieldset>',
                          '<fieldset class="field">',
                          ' <label for="jqxcheckboxvalue">value:</label>',
                          ' <input type="checkbox" name="value" id="jqxcheckboxvalue" ' +
                          'value='+($('#jqxcheckboxvalue').is(':checked'))+'>',
                          '</fieldset>',
                          '<fieldset class="field buttons">',
                          '<div id="confirmButtons">',
                          ' <button id="save_add_parameter" class="button blue">${translator("save").title()}</button>',
                          ' <button id="close_add_parameter" class="button gray">${translator("close").title()}</button>',
                          '</div>',
                          '</fieldset>',
                          '</div></div>',
                      ].join('');
```

How can I get the state of the checkbox?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

```
alert($('#jqxcheckboxvalue').is(':checked'));
```

Comment: I use the pop up window to edit the value, alert() doesn't allow it and even if I use is(:checked) in the value of the input it doesn't get anything

Comment: @Camilla Try `var isChecked = $('#jqxcheckboxvalue').is(':checked'); alert(isChecked)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:checked` and `length` as follow:

```
if($('#jqxcheckboxvalue:checked').length > 0)
```

Comment: `#jqxcheckboxvalue` is unique, don't need to check length

Comment: It has checked pseudo class, so it is checking if checked + id 's length is greater than 0 or not and note the id alone